# SVG resizing height on window resize, also center to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

So I've run into troubles when making my web app responsive. I've managed to make it so that the SVG adapts when the width is resized, but I've run into trouble with height.

The best solution I've come up with for height resize is the following js/jQuery code:

```
        function updateWindow(){
            var y = (($(window).height()));
            svgMap.style.height=y;
        }
        updateWindow();
        window.onresize = updateWindow;
```

What this does is set the SVG viewport height to equal that of the window.. This works in a sense that it centers the SVG with the browser window's height. Not so excellent, it screws up on mobile devices and adds a strange top-margin almost. It also makes the SVG slightly smaller unless I multiply "y" by some value greater than one. Doing so, however, increases the margin-top esque gap. How troublesome..

You can view the demo here:
http://zadias.me/SVG/Harrison%20Wilson/HarrisonWils.html

and the demo w/o the height center change here: http://zadias.me/SVG/Harrison%20Wilson/HarrisonWils%20-%20Copy.html

To sum things up, How does one go about centering an SVG within an `<object>` tag, horizontally AND vertically. Also, I would like it so that the SVG map itself fills the wrapper container.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**: So I've given up on trying to get it to just fit the parent's height.. Instead I just wrote some JS that will prompt the user with a warning if the height is too small that it will cause overflow of the page. I also made it so that it would be styled perfectly by adding inline CSS to each page, accompanied with media queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the SVG's width and height to 100%, ie.:

```
<svg width="100%" height=="100%">...
```

then it should just be a matter of resizing the container that the SVG is inside.  The preserveAspectRatio setting of "xMidYMid meet" should then centre it vertically.

Comment: Still no vertical scaling.. I even tried adding `width="100%" height="100%"` to the `<object>` in the source code, no cigar.

Comment: You want vertical scaling?  Do you mean you want it strectched horizontally *and* vertically?  If that is the case, use `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.  If you want it so that it scales to fill the entire container (meaning some of the svg spills outside it and is clipped) use `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`.

Comment: I want it to fit the window and be entirely seen by the user. I do not want overflowing/clipping, as you said. I tried `preserveAspectRatio="none"`, didn't work.